# Random Walk on Integer Line

Tags: probability, random-walk

Suppose we are doing a random walk on the infinite integer line and that we take $2n$ total steps. At every step of this walk, the position of the walker is an integer point on this line. For the next step of this walk, the walker moves to one of the two adjacent/neighboring integer points with equal probability (assume we start at integer 0). Let $S_l$ and $S_r$ be random variables denoting the number of leftward steps and rightward steps made over the whole $2n$-step walk, respectively.

There are two things I would like to show:

(1): For any $t > 0$, there exists a constant $c > 0$ such that Pr$[|S_l - S_r| > c\sqrt{n}] \leq t$.

(2): Derive a bound on $\beta$ given that  Pr$[|S_l - S_r| > \beta] \geq 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ (i.e., find a bound on $\beta$ that gives us a high probability guarantee).

We may assume that $S_l \geq S_r$.

One approach I'm considering is that we can take $|S_l - S_r|$ as a random variable $D_{2n}$ denoting the distance from the origin after $2n$ steps. Now we can compute $E[D_{2n}] \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sqrt{2n}$. I'd imagine that at this point I'd either need to apply a Chernoff bound or the Chebyshev inequality, but I'm not sure how to apply either in this context.

Comment: You could define $X_i$ as the random jump at step $i$, with $\{X_i\}$ i.i.d. and $P[X_i=-1]=P[X_i=1]=1/2$, and define $G_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.  The central limit theorem ensures $G_n$ is approximately Gaussian with mean 0 and variance $Var(X_1)$, and $D_n = \sqrt{n}|G_n|$.

Comment: Without the Gaussian approx, you could use a Hoeffding bound. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding's_inequality

Comment: @Michael It turns out that we're permitted to assume that $S_l \geq S_r$. With this assumption I managed to derive a bound $t = e^{-c^2/8}$ for (1) using the upper multiplicative Chernoff bound by just rearranging the inequality $S_l - S_r > c \sqrt{n}$. However, I'm not sure how to approach (2), since the equality is flipped.

Comment: You can use $\beta=0$ for the second part. If you want a better $\beta$ perhaps the Gaussian approximation is useful.